# Why is $('a b') less efficient than $('b', 'a')?

Tags: jquery, performance

I am making a function to convert RGB colors to Hex codes and vice versa. The HTML is a group of 6 inputs in a div (its ID is rgbHex). I want this function to be called when the user types into any of the 6 text boxes.

For those who want code:

```
<div id="rgbHex">
    <input id="hr" /> &nbsp; <input id="hg" /> &nbsp; <input id="hb" /> <br/>
    <input id="rr" /> &nbsp; <input id="rg" /> &nbsp; <input id="rb" /> <br/>
</div>
```

Since the webpage I'm putting it on has multiple `<input>`s, I want to make sure that the function is only called when the user types in one of these 6 text boxes.

When I type `$('#rgbHex input')` into my IDE, the warning it gives me is `Inefficient jQuery Usage`. The warning goes away when I use `$('input', '#rgbHex')`. So my question is this: why is the latter more efficient than the former?

Comment: There's nothing "inefficient" about `$('#rgbHex input')`.  You'd have to run performance tests in several browsers to see if `$('input', '#rgbHex')` is slightly faster or not, but I rather doubt the performance difference would be relevant in just installing some event handlers.  FYI, the third option to consider is `$('#rgbHex').find('input')`.  All should produce the same results, but are simply different ways of expressing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do you have `$('#rgbHex input')` multiple times in your code? My IDE (PhpStorm) gives that warning whenever it sees you using the same selector twice -- it wants you to assign it to a variable rather than repeating the selection.

Comment: I am not sure that $('input', '#rgbHex') is totally valid.  I think the second selector will be ignored, therefore you are selecting *all* inputs.  Have you validated this?

Comment: It even complains if you write `$(this)` multiple times.

Comment: @Brandon The 2nd argument is the [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1). `$('input', '#rgbHex')` is similar to `$('#rgbHex').find('input')`.

Comment: @Barmar No, I'm using IDEA, and I get that warning a lot too, but I'm only using this one once.

Comment: @Brandon Is kind of right. The documentation says that `context` is an element or jQuery object. But it happens to work with a selector string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very inefficient, but it could be micro optimized by separating the context out, as suggested by your editor; it roughly equates to:

```
$('#rgbHex').find('input')
```

This internally is optimized to use `getElementById()` and `getElementsByTagName()` immediately without having to use Sizzle to perform the query.

As with anything, whether this makes a difference can only be objectively determined by doing your own measurements.